# Integration over multiple variables in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a 5d integral into python, however am i getting a syntax error when defining my parameters for nquad:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import time

#
#  Integrand
#
def f(*args):
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = args
    return math.exp(0.5*x1**2(2 + math.sin(14))) + math.exp(0.25*x2**2(2 + math.sin(13))) + math.exp(0.1*x3**2(2 + math.sin(12))) + math.exp(0.1*x4**2(2 + math.sin(11)) + math.exp(0.1*x5**2(2 + math.sin(10)))


ans = nquad(f,[[0,1] [0,1,],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]])
print("5D Integral between 0 and 1 = ", ans)
```

Could anyone explain where i have gone wrong?

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis here `math.exp(0.1*x4**2(2 + math.sin(11))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various syntax errors in the code.

1. You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the `return`
2. No `*` sign for multiplying in `return`, this will lead to `TypeError: int object is not callable`. Because python will try to call in like a function.
3. There is a missing `,` in the list that you pass to `nquad()`.

**Fixed code**

```
def f(*args):
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = args
    return math.exp(0.5*x1**2*(2 + math.sin(14))) + math.exp(0.25*x2**2*(2 + math.sin(13))) + math.exp(0.1*x3**2*(2 + math.sin(12))) + \
    math.exp(0.1*x4**2*(2 + math.sin(11)) + math.exp(0.1*x5**2*(2 + math.sin(10))))

ans = nquad(f,[[0,1] ,[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]])
print("5D Integral between 0 and 1 = ", ans)
```